# How to use can_add_related in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I've read about the can_add_related feature here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9071

I tried using it this way:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    self.fields['person'].can_add_related = False
    return super(OperationAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

But this throws a TypeError and I don't know how to solve this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is probably coming in late. But for other viewers reference,

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ProductAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['category'].widget.can_add_related = False
    return form
```

Comment: for everyone who's trying that, this simply works, even with Django 1.7 - **but** not with Inlines. For them I ended up with overwriting the widgets, as explained by @Seether , see here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425818/django-1-7-removing-add-button-from-inline-form)

Comment: See this answer to the question linked in @normic's comment for a much conciser solution for inlines (using get_formset instead of get_form) http://stackoverflow.com/a/37558444/1302095

Answer (score 3):

`can_add_related` seems to be [an attribute on the widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L224), not the field, so try:

```
self.fields['person'].widget.can_add_related = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, with changing widget options *before* the form is instantiated:

```
class MyAdmin(django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(formfield, "widget"):
            formfield.widget.can_add_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
        else:
            pass  # this relation doesn't have an admin page to add/delete/change

        return formfield
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, if you are defining an Inline model and use it in your admin, would be to [overwrite the get_formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_formset) method:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel
    extra = 0
    min_num = 1
    max_num = 10
    fields = [
        'some_field'
    ]

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        fs = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        fs.form.base_fields['some_field'].widget.can_add_related = False
        fs.form.base_fields['some_field'].widget.can_change_related = False
        fs.form.base_fields['some_field'].widget.can_delete_related = False
        return fs
```

Answer (score 0):

For TabularInline you can combine the answer from @Art and @babis21:

We can use the @Art answer here as well using the following:

```py
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        res = super().get_formset(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
        for formfield in res.form.base_fields.values():
            if hasattr(formfield, "widget"):
                formfield.widget.can_add_related = False
                formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False
                formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded this mixin:

```
class AdminModelNoAddOrChangeForeignKeyMixin:
    # For admin.ModelAdmin
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in form.base_fields.items():
            if isinstance(self.model._meta.get_field(field_name), ForeignKey):
                field.widget.can_add_related = False
                field.widget.can_change_related = False
        return form

    # For admin.TabularInline and admin.StackedInline
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        fs = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field in fs.form.base_fields.items():
            if isinstance(self.model._meta.get_field(field_name), ForeignKey):
                field.widget.can_add_related = False
                field.widget.can_change_related = False
        return fs
```

Works for all foreign key fields as mixin for Inline and ModelAdmin:

```
class MyInline(AdminModelNoAddOrChangeForeignKeyMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    whatever

class DigitalDistributionDataAdmin(AdminModelNoAddOrChangeForeignKeyMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    whatever
```