# django admin: how to disable edit and delete link for foreignkey

Tags: python, django

In django admin site, if the model has a foreignkey, by default it will be a select input and there are three links(edit, add, delete) like below.
How to disable these links **only for foreignkey**?
If using has_delete_permission, they it cannot be deleted in its own change form either.

Default:
[image: default]

Expected:
[image: after]

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348422/4872140 source at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/

Comment: it helps. can_delete_related is in widget ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not exactly a documented feature. Furthermore, [formfield_for_dbfield](https://github.com/django/django/blob/379bf1a2d41494360d86bc3cf8adc482abca5d63/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L131) is a damned mess (just as most of the `django.contrib.admin`). But it's the cleanest approach I found, and it works fine for me.

```
class MyAdmin(django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(*args, **kwargs)

        formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False
        formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
        # formfield.widget.can_add_related = False  # can change this, too
        # formfield.widget.can_view_related = False  # can change this, too

        return formfield
```

Answer (score 10):

in admin.py create a def under your model ModelAdmin class. Choose the options for Add, Change or Delete related to the foreign_key field, keeping the ones you desire to hide and deleting (or changing boolean from False to True) for the ones you wante to show:

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        field = form.base_fields["your_foreign_key_field"]
        field.widget.can_add_related = False
        field.widget.can_change_related = False
        field.widget.can_delete_related = False
        return form
```

Comment: This worked great in the base admin, but I can't get it to also work in an inline (`StackedInline`). Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Answer to my own question^^ use `get_formset` instead! Worked like a charm: ```def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        field = formset.form.base_fields["impersonating"]```

Comment: @arielkaluzhny I would suggest posting a separate answer so that you can show your answer with full code formatting! Cheers

Comment: Thanks @GregSadetsky, I did that. :)

Answer (score 4):

(Transferring my comment to an answer)

The above answers work great for regular admin pages. To get this to work in an admin inline (ex: `admin.StackedInline`), use `get_formset` instead of `get_form`:

```
def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
     formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
     field = formset.form.base_fields["your_foreign_key_field"]
     field.widget.can_add_related = False
     field.widget.can_change_related = False
     field.widget.can_delete_related = False
     return formset
```

Comment: you're missing a `def` in front of the `get_formset` :-) otherwise looks great!

Comment: you're missing `return formset`, anyway this is what I was looking for and it works well!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the completeness of [Art's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58991310/9022092) answer:

For an Inline (`admin.StackedInline`, `admin.TabularInline`) you can use [formfield_for_dbfield](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d287294885e116c49c87f0c663068511a8402c0f/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L149) as well:

```
class MyInline(django.contrib.admin.TabularInline):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, *args, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_dbfield(*args, **kwargs)
        if formfield:
            formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_add_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_view_related = False

        return formfield
```

`formfield` is somehow `None` sometimes for Inlines so you need to add the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['xxx'].widget.can_delete_related = False
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: ```fields``` is ```None``` in ```__init___```